# Mounting SMB share on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I am having difficulty in mounting a Seagate freeagent USB external drive in Ubuntu 19.04. The drive is attached to a HG635 router at 192.168.1.1.
I'm able to view the shared directory using 'files' and can see the smb: location, `smb://super%20router/share/`

I've created a local directory for the mount, /mnt/HG635.

The output from `sudo smbclient -L //192.168.1.1` is

```
    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service ()
    share           Disk      linux
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------
    SUPER ROUTER         

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
    WORKGROUP            SUPER ROUTER
```

The output from `sudo smbtree` is

```
WORKGROUP
    \\SUPER ROUTER          
        \\SUPER ROUTER\share            linux
        \\SUPER ROUTER\IPC$             IPC Service ()
```

I've added the following line to fstab

```
//192.168.1.1/share /mnt/HG635 cifs guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

When I run sudo mount -a the response is

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I get the same response when trying to mount the drive from the command line using `sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/share /mnt/HG635/`

I have the latest version of cifs & cifs-utils installed.

I also tried `gio mount smb://super%20router/share` and the response was

```
gio: smb://super%20router/share/: Location is already mounted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your router but I suspect it is running an old dialect of smb.

Add vers=1.0 to your list of options:

```
//192.168.1.1/share /mnt/HG635 cifs guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0 0 0
```

In addition it may also require an earlier security mode which would be another option: `sec=ntlm`

Comment: I was having trouble mounting my rather old OpenMediaVault SMB share after upgrading to ubuntu 20.04 - adding `vers=1.0` worked for me! thanks